# System of equations matrices

Tags: matrix-equations

Please help me in slicing this question.Given a matrix and need to find 
The locus of all (a,b) € R2 such that this system has atleast TWO DISTINCT solutions for (x1,x2,x3,x4) is ____

Options are
Parabola; straight line ; entire plane of R2 ; a point

[image]

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Hint: observe that your question is equivalent to ask "for what values of $\;a,\,b\;$ is the given matrix **singular** ?"

Comment: I got an other expression for minor M 14 as  3a-8b=114.if we do all the 3x3 determinants of minors as zero.we will get some set of a,b values.how to know the locus.

Comment: if we get two singular solutions  ,what does it mean..i dont know how to find this locus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, your homogeneous system has at least two different solutions iff the coefficients' matrix is singular iff its determinant is zero:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&2&3&4\\
5&6&7&8\\
a&9&b&10\\
6&8&10&13\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{\begin{cases}R_2-5R_1\\R_3-aR_1\\R_4-6R_1\\{}&{}\end{cases}}=\begin{vmatrix}1&2&3&4\\
0&-4&-8&-12\\
0&9-2a&b-3a&10-4a\\
0&-4&-8&-11\end{vmatrix}=$$$${}$$

$$=\begin{vmatrix}
-4&-8&-12\\
9-2a&b-3a&10-4a\\
-4&-8&-11\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-R_1}=\begin{vmatrix}
-4&-8&-12\\
9-2a&b-3a&10-4a\\
0&0&1\end{vmatrix}=$$$${}$$

$$=\begin{vmatrix}
-4&-8\\
9-2a&b-3a&\end{vmatrix}=12a-4b+72-16a\stackrel?=0\iff a+b=18$$